# Anchor recylerview on Imageview inside AppBarLayout,CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Following is my `xml` code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="185dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/card_dark_text"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAirportBg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/screen_bg"
                android:tint="#8a000000"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:layout_behavior=".view.ToolbarBackgroundAlphaBehavior"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                app:theme="@style/TransperantToolbar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_recycler_slide_in"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/imgAirportBg"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now want to anchor `Recylerview` a little bit on `ImageView` imgAirportBg which is inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. how to do this?

I have added following to `RecyclerView`

```
    app:layout_anchor="@id/imgAirportBg"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center|bottom"
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding following line to recyclerview xml

```
app:behavior_overlapTop="28dp"
```